# Upgrade weblogic to JPA 2.1

Tags: weblogic12c, jpa-2.1

By default, weblogic is using JPA 2.0. Is there a way to enable JPA 2.1 for weblogic 12.1.3 other than add pre_classpath in startWebLogic.cmd or OPatch?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can start your server thru NodeManager, and under:

YOUR_DOMAIN --> Environment --> Server --> YOUR_SERVER --> Class Path:

You must add all classpath for your Managed Server, and there you can add JPA 2.1 implementation.

Comment: @devwbcl Well, I don't think this is a good approach because it requires the whole team to add classpath manually.

Comment: You need to modify the classpath with the new implementation.
This is done only once.